# Error when running Spyder after installing Anaconda in a HPC Linux Environment

Tags: python, linux, spyder, hpc

I'm trying to run Spyder in a HPC environment but getting an error I can't find any solutions for

I'm new to working in a HPC linux system and trying to install packages relevant to scientific computing. I installed Anaconda using wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2021.05-Linux-x86_64.sh and let it execute. Most things seem to work fine, and I'm able to work in jupyter, ipython, etc. but when I run spyder I get a really long backtrace and I'm not sure what's wrong. I tried uninstalling by deleting the anaconda3 folder, updating packages, but nothing seems to be working to actually run Spyder. Going through anaconda navigator doesn't work either. It's worth noting that this is not my personal machine, it's an HPC cluster.

```
Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7c619)[0x7ff2602d0619]
/lib64/libLLVM-3.9-mesa.so(_ZNSt6locale5_Impl16_M_install_facetEPKNS_2idEPKNS_5facetE+0x142)[0x7ff22e73bfa2]
/lib64/libLLVM-3.9-mesa.so(_ZNSt6locale5_ImplC1Em+0x1e3)[0x7ff22e73c433]
/lib64/libLLVM-3.9-mesa.so(_ZNSt6locale18_S_initialize_onceEv+0x15)[0x7ff22e73d3a5]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(pthread_once+0x50)[0x7ff260623e20]
/lib64/libLLVM-3.9-mesa.so(_ZNSt6locale13_S_initializeEv+0x21)[0x7ff22e73d3f1]
/lib64/libLLVM-3.9-mesa.so(_ZNSt6localeC2Ev+0x13)[0x7ff22e73d433]
/home/3279/anaconda3/lib/libspatialindex_c.so.6(SIDX_Version+0x33)[0x7ff22450dcc3]
/home/3279/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/../../libffi.so.7(+0x69dd)[0x7ff260a3d9dd]
/home/3279/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/../../libffi.so.7(+0x6067)[0x7ff260a3d067]
/home/3279/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(_ctypes_callproc+0x8f3)[0x7ff25934cd03]
/home/3279/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x15064)[0x7ff25934d064]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyObject_MakeTpCall+0x23c)[0x564e3d367dbc]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4596)[0x564e3d3f3666]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x300)[0x564e3d3bd270]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCode+0x23)[0x564e3d452543]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x256433)[0x564e3d47a433]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x1470e9)[0x564e3d36b0e9]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(PyVectorcall_Call+0x33a)[0x564e3d37829a]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5326)[0x564e3d3f43f6]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x300)[0x564e3d3bd270]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x1e3)[0x564e3d3be0a3]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x103a61)[0x564e3d327a61]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x10b)[0x564e3d3bdfcb]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x103a40)[0x564e3d327a40]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x10b)[0x564e3d3bdfcb]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x1035db)[0x564e3d3275db]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x10b)[0x564e3d3bdfcb]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x1035db)[0x564e3d3275db]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x10b)[0x564e3d3bdfcb]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x15babd)[0x564e3d37fabd]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs+0x127)[0x564e3d39b367]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject+0x51c)[0x564e3d356b6c]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x3664)[0x564e3d3f2734]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x300)[0x564e3d3bd270]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCode+0x23)[0x564e3d452543]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x256433)[0x564e3d47a433]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x1470e9)[0x564e3d36b0e9]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(PyVectorcall_Call+0x33a)[0x564e3d37829a]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5326)[0x564e3d3f43f6]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x300)[0x564e3d3bd270]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x1e3)[0x564e3d3be0a3]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x103a61)[0x564e3d327a61]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x10b)[0x564e3d3bdfcb]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x103a40)[0x564e3d327a40]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x10b)[0x564e3d3bdfcb]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x1035db)[0x564e3d3275db]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x10b)[0x564e3d3bdfcb]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x1035db)[0x564e3d3275db]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x10b)[0x564e3d3bdfcb]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x15babd)[0x564e3d37fabd]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs+0x127)[0x564e3d39b367]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject+0x51c)[0x564e3d356b6c]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x3664)[0x564e3d3f2734]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x300)[0x564e3d3bd270]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(PyEval_EvalCode+0x23)[0x564e3d452543]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x256433)[0x564e3d47a433]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x1470e9)[0x564e3d36b0e9]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(PyVectorcall_Call+0x33a)[0x564e3d37829a]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5326)[0x564e3d3f43f6]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyEval_EvalCodeWithName+0x300)[0x564e3d3bd270]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x1e3)[0x564e3d3be0a3]
/home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python(+0x103a61)[0x564e3d327a61]
======= Memory map: ========
564e3d224000-564e3d283000 r--p 00000000 00:7b 27412                      /home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python3.8
564e3d283000-564e3d47c000 r-xp 0005f000 00:7b 27412                      /home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python3.8
564e3d47c000-564e3d562000 r--p 00258000 00:7b 27412                      /home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python3.8
564e3d563000-564e3d568000 r--p 0033e000 00:7b 27412                      /home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python3.8
564e3d568000-564e3d5a0000 rw-p 00343000 00:7b 27412                      /home/3279/anaconda3/bin/python3.8
564e3d5a0000-564e3d5c0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
564e3e75d000-564e400db000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7ff220000000-7ff220021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff220021000-7ff224000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff2243ca000-7ff22440a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22440a000-7ff22443e000 r--p 00000000 00:7b 352737                     /home/3279/anaconda3/lib/libspatialindex.so.6.1.1
7ff22443e000-7ff2244ca000 r-xp 00034000 00:7b 352737                     /home/3279/anaconda3/lib/libspatialindex.so.6.1.1
7ff2244ca000-7ff2244ea000 r--p 000c0000 00:7b 352737                     /home/3279/anaconda3/lib/libspatialindex.so.6.1.1
7ff2244ea000-7ff2244f0000 r--p 000df000 00:7b 352737                     /home/3279/anaconda3/lib/libspatialindex.so.6.1.1
7ff2244f0000-7ff2244f1000 rw-p 000e5000 00:7b 352737                     /home/3279/anaconda3/lib/libspatialindex.so.6.1.1
7ff2244f1000-7ff2244fb000 r--p 00000000 00:7b 351692                     /home/3279/anaconda3/lib/libspatialindex_c.so.6.1.1
7ff2244fb000-7ff224518000 r-xp 0000a000 00:7b 351692                     /home/3279/anaconda3/lib/libspatialindex_c.so.6.1.1
7ff224518000-7ff224520000 r--p 00027000 00:7b 351692                     /home/3279/anaconda3/lib/libspatialindex_c.so.6.1.1
7ff224520000-7ff224521000 ---p 0002f000 00:7b 351692                     /home/3279/anaconda3/lib/libspatialindex_c.so.6.1.1
7ff224521000-7ff224522000 r--p 0002f000 00:7b 351692                     /home/3279/anaconda3/lib/libspatialindex_c.so.6.1.1
7ff224522000-7ff224523000 rw-p 00030000 00:7b 351692                     /home/3279/anaconda3/lib/libspatialindex_c.so.6.1.1
7ff224523000-7ff2245e3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff2245e3000-7ff2245e5000 r--p 00000000 00:7b 24472                      /home/3279/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_lsprof.cpython-38-x
7ff2245e5000-7ff2245e8000 r-xp 00002000 00:7b 24472                      /home/3279/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_lsprof.cpython-38-x
7ff2245e8000-7ff2245e9000 r--p 00005000 00:7b 24472                      /home/3279/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_lsprof.cpython-38-x
```